# Can I check references against null or a certain type of value?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, null, dereference

I wanted to know if I can check a reference against being invalid. I believe I can, but I'm not sure. Related to this, I would also like to know if in the following case I am "dereferencing" the pointer:

```
struct Texture { int width; };

void useTexture(Texture& texture)
{
    int a = texture.width;
    //Exception thrown: read access violation.
texture was nullptr. 
// When I hover the mouse over the argument it says "struct at null"
}

int main()
{
    Texture* obj = nullptr;
    useTexture(*obj); // This is using the dereference operator, 
                      // but no exception is thrown here.
}
```

The exception only occurs in the useTexture() function. In this case when passing the *obj argument to the function, it's not reading data from this location, it's just giving the address to the reference, I assume in no different way than would happen when passing a pointer. So even if I used the dereference operator did it actually dereference the pointer? I don't think so.

Also I would like to know if there's a way to check in the useTexture() function if the reference is valid. In the debugger when I hover over the argument it says the struct is at null, and when it throws the exception it says that texture is nullptr. I'm assuming it's saying nullptr because its address is 0x00, because texture isn't a pointer at all, but a reference.

Likewise, if I do:

```
Texture* obj = (Texture*)0x80;
useTexture(*obj);
```

Instead of saying "struct at null" it says it can't read the data, and when throwing the exception it says "invalid memory access at 0x80". This I understand.

What I wanted to do was to have a safety check in the function that checks if its valid. Remembering that people say references can't be null, I thought I'd have to change the function to take a pointer, and I could check against a pointer value, like nullptr. But from what I've seen references also have addresses, and can be null. Is there a way to check if the reference is valid without changing it to a pointer argument? I guess the dereference question is a separate question, but didn't want to make two questions.

Edit: I was just testing, and thought I could do something like:

```
if ((Texture*)&texture == nullptr) return;
```

Instead of checking for nullptr at the call site.

Answer (score 1):

Doing something like this:

```
 A * a = nullptr;
 A b = * a;
```

Is undefined in C++. It's also undefined even if you don't create the named variable, because the compiler may decide to create a nameless temporary by dereferencing `a`. So this statement:

```
 * a;
```

is also undefined.

Comment: In the first case it's reading the address the pointer's holding. I understand that's a no-go. When passing to a reference when using the dereference operator I'm doubting whether it's dereferencing it because it's just sending its address value, much like it does to another pointer.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that when I do callfunction(*obj) I doubt that it's doing any dereferencing at all, the reference takes the address of the object, that's all, right?